# Invalid digit, Value '"', Pos 0, Type: Decimal in Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

While trying to load data into redshift from AWS S3, I am facing an issue with any column in the redshift table of type decimal. I am able to load non-decimal number in redshift, but can't able load datatype like Numeric(18,4).

DF schema in S3: *A Integer, B string, C decimal(18,4), D timestamp*
Redshift table schema: *A INTEGER, B VARCHAR(20), C NUMERIC(18,4), D TIMESTAMP*

Error Message from stl_load_errors table:

> Invalid digit, Value '"', Pos 0, Type: Decimal

Data that redshift is trying to add:

```
2|sample_string||2021-04-03|
```

**Why decimal column is coming as Empty or NULL??** AS you see above, the redshift data all data come in proper format except decimal column which is empty.

This is the code that I am using to load data into redshift from S3:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("App_name").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
spark.conf.set("spark.kryo.unsafe", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1024m")

df = spark.read.parquet(s3_input_path)

pre_query = """ 
  begin;
  create table {} (like {});
  end;
  """.format(temp_table,actual_table_name)

post_query = """ 
  begin;
  --some action
  insert into {} select * from {};
  end;
  """.format(actual_table_name,temp_table)

df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.redshiftLib') \
      .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://aws.redshift.amazonaws.sampleurl.com:5439/") \
      .option("user","UserName") \
      .option("preactions",pre_query) \
      .option("password","Password") \
      .option("dbtable","table_name" ) \
      .option("extracopyoptions", "ACCEPTINVCHARS AS '?' TRUNCATECOLUMNS") \
      .option("postactions",post_query) \
      .options("tempformat", "CSV GZIP") \
      .option("tempdir", "s3a://aws-bucket/") \
      .option("csvseparator","|") \
      .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials","true")\
      .mode("append") \
      .save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, I was using Spark 2.x. In order to save tempdir in CSV format, you need spark 3.x. You can use latest version, `3.0.0-preview1`.

You can upgrade your spark
**or**
you can use your command like `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:3.0.0-preview1....`

Explanation:
When writing to Redshift, data is first stored in a temp folder in S3 before being loaded into Redshift. The default format used for storing temp data between Apache Spark and Redshift is Spark-Avro. However, Spark-Avro stores a decimal as a binary, which is interpreted by Redshift as empty strings or nulls.

But I want to improve performance and remove this blank issue, for that purpose CSV format is best suitable. I was using Spark 2.x which by default use Avro tempformat, even if we mention it externally.

So after giving 3.0.0-preview1 package with command, It can now use the features that are present in Spark 3.x.

Reference:
https://kb.databricks.com/data/redshift-fails-decimal-write.html
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/308